# Yii2: /assets/1ecfb338/css/bootstrap.css just loads page, not css

Tags: nginx, yii2

I am having trouble with Yii2 in that it won't load the bootstrap.css file. In fact it's not being created. And when I try to load http://frontend.local/assets/1ecfb338/css/bootstrap.css, it just loads the Yii front page, not the css file.

Why would this happen? Could it be my Nginx config?

```
server {
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";
listen    80;

server_name frontend.local;

root /var/www/frontend/web;
index $yii_bootstrap;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log info;


location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git|sql) {
    deny all;
}

sendfile off;
}
```

This is running in a Linux VM.

Answer (score 1):

The file does not exist. Your `try_files` directive instructs `nginx` to serve `/$yii_bootstrap` whenever the file does not exist, irrespective of file time.

If you add a specific location for static resource files, you will be able to sent an expiry (which is a common strategy) and at the same time, remove them from the file `try_files` test.

Try adding this to your `server` block:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 24h;
#   log_not_found off;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the assest directory are create dinamically when an url request involve the related resoource.

You can try to remove (delete) the content of the directory related th boostrap and see what's happend when you invoce the frontend (or your webApp)  url

Be sure your layout contain (for frontend) :

```
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;


AppAsset::register($this);
```

and your    `frontend/assets/AppAsset.php`  contain reference to bootstrap at least like this  (the yii default  fro advanced template)

> ```
> <?php
> /**
>  * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
>  * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
>  * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
>  */
>
> namespace frontend\assets;
>
> use yii\web\AssetBundle;
>
> /**
> * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
> * @since 2.0
> */
> class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
> {
>   public $basePath = '@webroot';
>   public $baseUrl = '@web';
>   public $css = [
>     'css/site.css',
>   ];
>   public $js = [
>   ];
>   public $depends = [
>     'yii\web\YiiAsset',
>     'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
>   ];
> }
> ```

and obviuosly you have a correct yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAssest content